# API Management API Schema-Definition create - Multiple definitions under 1 schema at a time

Tags: powershell, azure-api-management, azure-rest-api

I am trying to use the REST API PUT call to

```
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/{serviceName}/apis/{apiName}/schemas/{schemaId}?api-version=2021-01-01-preview
```

as an equivalent powershell cmdlet doesn't function as expected for adding schema-definitions. But the problem is even with REST API call, it is able to add one definition at a time. If my schema has more than 1 definition, when I fire the 2nd and subsequent PUT call it overwrites the previously written definition, and finally only 1 definition remains. Tried adding the If-Match to Request Header on 2nd and subsequent calls too, but in vain.

Tried adding multiple definitions under "schemas" as array of json, but even if that creates multiple definitions in 1 go, the DefinitionName are 0, 1, 2, 3 etc. and not actual names given in the input json body.

Multiple Definition Sample below -

```
  "properties": {
    "contentType": "application/vnd.oai.openapi.components+json",
    "document": {
      "components": {
        "schemas": [
          {
            "Definition1": {
              "type": "object",
              "properties": {
                "String1": {
                  "type": "string"
                }
              }
            },
            "Definition2": {
              "type": "object",
              "properties": {
                "String2": {
                  "type": "integer"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        ]**
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Does the PUT call allow putting definitions at once and if so, how?

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue in the JSON being PUT on the REST API request.

The multiple definition json has to be like this -

```
{
"properties": {
    "contentType": "application/vnd.oai.openapi.components+json",
    "document": {
      "components": {
        "schemas": {
            "Definition1": {
              "type": "object",
              "properties": {
                "String1": {
                  "type": "string"
                }
              }
            },
            "Definition2": {
              "type": "object",
              "properties": {
                "String2": {
                  "type": "integer"
                }
              }
            }
          }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The definitions given under "schemas" need not be put inside []. Just specify as per the above json structuring and we should be good.